# Recursive Diamond Solution not indenting itself in order to get what I expect from the JUnit tests

Tags: java

I am trying to get a diamond to print recursively using a String method. The problem I'm having is that my code does not give me what I expect it prints out the exact number of '*' that I am using to try to get the shape of the diamond to come out, but it is not properly formatting it the way that I intended. `

public static String printRhombus(int i, int n) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

```
    if (i > n) {
        return sb.toString();
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < (n - i) / 2; j++) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        sb.append("*");
    }

    sb.append("\n");

    if (i < n) {
        sb.append(printRhombus(i + 2, n));
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < (n - i) / 2; j++) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        sb.append("*");
    }

    sb.append("\n");

    return sb.toString();
}`
```

[JUnit test of what I expect and what is actually happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdRUv.png)
The code is meant to take let's say a height of 5, this method will only work with odd numbers, and that will be the amount of lines that the shape must be. But the very middle of the shape so in this case for 5 line 3 should have "*****" and than just mirror what was shown above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are not properly indenting the spaces in the second half of the diamond. You need to adjust the number of spaces you append before the second set of '*' to make sure the diamond is properly formatted. Here is an updated version of your code that should work:

import java.util.Scanner;
public class prog{
public static String diamond (int i, int n){       StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();

```
if (i > n) {
    return sb.toString();
}

// first half of diamond
for (int j = 0; j < (n - i) / 2; j++) {
    sb.append(" ");
}

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    sb.append("*");
}

sb.append("\n");

// recursive call for first half
sb.append(diamond (i + 2, n));

// second half of diamond
for (int j = 0; j < (n - i) / 2; j++) {
    sb.append(" ");
}

for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    sb.append("*");
}

sb.append("\n");

return sb.toString();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("please enter the size");
    int size=sc.nextInt();
    System.out.println(diamond (1, size));
    sc.close();
}
```

}

Comment: this does not solve my problems. It also looks the exact same.

Comment: I have  edited the code check it out it's working fine